# Ant build for blackberry when startup tier is 6

Tags: blackberry

I have two blackberry library applications  and one cldc application.

I want to compile a build.xml integrating all this.

cldc  and library 2 refers to library 1.

library 1 has startup tier as 6 which means install during device start.

library 2 can be either 7 or 6.

how to achieve the ota build which does have all these functionalities?

Answer (score 1):

Consider [BB Ant Tools](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/)

JDP element of [RAPC task](http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/docs#rapc) allows setting startup tier for the compiling cod file.